# How to do a calculation with a column in database and insert the result Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, time-and-attendance

Basically i have to count the monthly meal allowance for each of the employee based on their monthly attendance, which only leave me with just one table, **attendance table**

The calculation for the meal allowance is pretty simple, i only need to count how many days the employee attended and calculate it with one number (this number should be dynamic or editable)

```
this is the example of the calculation:
number of attendance * 15.00 (editable number)
```

here's my data for **attendance table**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| attendance_id | emp_code | emp_name  |    date      | time_in | time_out |
|       1       |    ALB   |  Albert   | 2018.01.01   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
|       2       |    GlN   |  GLENN    | 2018.01.01   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
|       3       |    ALB   |  Albert   | 2018.01.02   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
|       4       |    GLN   |  GLENN    | 2018.01.02   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
|       5       |    ALB   |  Albert   | 2018.01.04   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
|       6       |    GLN   |  GLENN    | 2018.01.04   | 07.00   |  18.00   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far i already managed to count the monthly recap (by counting how many days they attended), this is my current condition:

```
------------------------------------------------
| emp_code   |   emp_name   |  days_attended    |
| ALB        |   Albert     |         3         |
| GLN        |   GLENN      |         3         |
-------------------------------------------------
```

This is my **controller**

```
    public function index(){
    $this->load->model('allowance_m');
    $data['query'] = $this->allowance_m->calculate();
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('allowance_v',$data);
    }
```

This is my **model** (allowance_m.php)

```
public function hitungabsen()
    {
        $this->db->select('attendance_id,emp_code,emp_name, COUNT(date) as days_attended');    
        $this->db->from('attendance');
        $this->db->group_by('emp_code');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

This is my **view** allowance_v.php

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><center>Employee Code</center></th>
                        <th><center>Employee Name</center></th>
                        <th><center>Days Attended</center></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <?php 
                    $no = 1;
                    foreach($query as $row){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->emp_code ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->emp_name ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->days_attended ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>          
                </table>
```

Now i really need to know how can i calculate the meal allowance with the inputted days attended, and after calculating the result, i need to insert the result into the database so that i can make a pdf report about that. the result should be like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| emp_code   |   emp_name   |  days_attended    |     meal allowance    |
| ALB        |   Albert     |         3         |(automaticaly updated) |
| GLN        |   GLENN      |         3         |(automaticaly updated) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE! Really need the answer as soon as possible, it means a lot for me

Comment: if meal allowance for a day is `15`, won't it be `15*3`, if the number of days attended by employee is 3? Am I getting your question clearly?

Comment: "i need to insert the result into the database" don't you mean update not insert? the graph that follows implies everything has been handled

Comment: yupp, true @ujjwalverma

Comment: the meal allowance hasn't been inserted to the database, so yeah i need to insert a new record or add a new column called meal allowance for the database. or maybe it should be called updating? sorry for my confusing statement :/ @Alex

Comment: you need to be a bit more clearer on your table structure. this is a separate table than attendance with those columns no?

Comment: yes, it should be on different table with the attendance. it would be great if i can make a new table called "allowance table" that filled with emp_code, emp_name, days_attended, and the meal allowance. so basicaly its like a recap table for the meal allowance hehe

Comment: alright well if you make a table exactly like the last one you described im pretty sure the answer i wrote will work nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really understand everything but this should work:

```
public function calc() {
    $meal_allowance = array_column($this->db->select('emp_code')->get('tablename')->result_array(), 'emp_code');
    $n = 15;
    $results = $this->hitungabsen();
    $this->db->trans_start();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $calc = intval($row->days_attended) * $n;
        if (in_array($row->emp_code, $meal_allowance)) {
            $this->db->update('tablename', array('meal_allowance' => $calc));
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'emp_code' => $row->emp_code,
                'emp_name' => $row->emp_name,
                'days_attended' => $row->days_attended,
                'meal_allowance' => $calc
            );
            $this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
        }
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $this->db->trans_status();
}
```

Updates if a record exists, inserts if it doesn't (assumed separate table with the specs in your last graph)

Comment: dang that was fast. thank you so much, will try it on later. will give you the update Asap! :D

Comment: fyi calc() function lives in the same model as the `hitungabsen` function

Comment: oh and btw, is there any chance that the $n could be filled by a form? since it has to be editable for the user?

Comment: yea just pass it to the model function `calc($n)` through a post var in the controller (obviously remove the defined var I have there now)